# Database only grabbing first row not current

Tags: php, database, datatables

So I have this table created that displays my datatable from phpmyadmin. When I click on edit game for say Id 9, it only shows data from row 8 and not row 9. I believe it has something to do with this piece of code because this is the only place that I see an error occurring. Can someone please help? If you need to see another piece of my code I can do so, thanks!

```
<?php 
$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "games";
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);


$sql = "SELECT Id,Dates,GameType,SubType,GameName,FeeType,EntryFee,MinPlayers,MaxPlayers,MaxEn 
tries,PrizeDetails,GameType2 FROM games";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $Id = $row["Id"];
    $Dates = $row["Dates"];
    $GameType = $row["GameType"];
    $SubType = $row["SubType"];
    $GameName = $row["GameName"];
    $FeeType = $row["FeeType"];
    $EntryFee = $row["EntryFee"];
    $MinPlayers = $row["MinPlayers"];
    $MaxPlayers = $row["MaxPlayers"];
    $MaxEntries = $row["MaxEntries"];
    $PrizeDetails = $row["PrizeDetails"];
    $GameType2 = $row["GameType2"];
    echo "<br/>
      <h1><center>  Edit Game </h1> <br/><br/>
```

Comment: What error message? ... and how are you filtering the `Id`, as there is no `WHERE` clause in the query?

Comment: I solved it, basically I assigned the Id number to my edit button and then passed on my edit button value through a form post. Thanks though